# Accessing new field value generated in SQL via dbContext

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm using `dbContext` and I am running a SQL query that is rather complex (just showing a simple example below), so to avoid having to run the query twice to get a count, I am using `COUNT AS` to return the total number of records as per other advice on this site.

But, I haven't been able to figure out how to access the resulting property:

```
using (var db = new DMSContext())
{
    string queryString = "select *, COUNT(1) OVER() AS TotalRecords FROM DMSMetas";
    var Metas = db.DMSMetas.SqlQuery(queryString).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i <= Metas.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        var Item = Metas[i];

        if (i == 0)
        {
           //Want to do this, but TotalRecords not part of the DMSMeta class. How to access the created column?
           Console.WriteLine("Total records found: " + Item.TotalRecords);
        }
    }
}
```

In the sample above, the SQL query generates the extra field `TotalRecords`. When I run the query in Management Studio, the results are as expected. But how do I access the `TotalRecords` field through `dbContext`?

I also tried including the `TotalRecords` field as part of the DMSMeta class, but then the SQL query fails  with the error that the `TotalRecords` field is specified twice. I tried creating a partial class for DMSMeta containing the `TotalRecords` field, but then the value remains the default value and is not updated during the query.

I also tried the following:

```
 db.Entry(Item).Property("TotalRecords").CurrentValue
```

But that generated an error too. Any help would be much appreciated - I am sure I am missing something obvious! All I want is to figure out a way to access the total number of records returned by the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create a new class (not an entity class but a pure DAO class) `DMSMetaWithCount` (self explanatory ?) and then

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<DMSMetaWithCount>("select *, COUNT(1) OVER() AS TotalRecords FROM DMSMetas");
```

please note that

- imho, `select *` is ALWAYS a bad practice.
- you will have no tracking on the not entity new class

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the slow response, but it helped!